# appending onto multiple elements in d3js

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

i wanted to know is there way to distinguish between which element of the parent array we are appending onto and append selectively?

eg:

```js
cell = parent.selectAll("g")
      .data(nodes)
      .enter()
   .append("svg:g")
   .filter(function(d,j){ var a = parent.selectAll("text");
  for(i=0;i<3;i++)
  if(a[i][0].innerHTML == d.parent.name)
  return true;
  return false;
   })
      .attr("class", "cell")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
      .on("click", function(d) { return zoom(node == d.parent ? root : d.parent); });
```

parent is cell of the previous iteration which consists of 3 cells

i want to writ a filter logic such that i can choose which object of nodes array goes to which cell

i can't hard code it as it will be dynamic>

thanks for you help.

Comment: Filter the data before passing it to D3.

Comment: ya, i figured it out later, thanks for the help!!